# Going from 26% width in desktop view to 90% width in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I created a module on our desktop view that has `width: 48%` but when in a smaller view such as a mobile device, it's too small and should be `width: 90%`

What is the best way to make that happen?

I'm already using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media Queries:

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L30mx48z/)

```
.module {
   width: 48%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .module {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

***Recommended Reading:***
[Logic in Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Comment: Is the max-width in the @media link an arbitrary number? Seems to work, but I just want to understand why use 480px verses 48%.

Comment: It is the width of the viewport (window size), therefore it has to be a fixed amount.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's simple enough to understand. Thanks a bunch!